# What does "almost everywhere" mean in convergence almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

[*Here*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convergence_Almost_Everywhere) is a very intuitive definition of convergence almost anywhere from ProofWiki:

> Sequence of function $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is said to converge almost everywhere on $ D$ to $ f$ if and only if $$\mu (\{x \in D \mid f_n(x) \text { does not converge to } f(x)\})=0$$ and we write it as $$f_n \xrightarrow {a.e.} f. $$

Intuitively, it means that the measure of the set, containing all the $x$'s that do not make $f_n$ converge to $ f $, is zero. But here comes my question: How does the adjective "almost everywhere" fit in?  Am I correct in saying that the adjective "almost everywhere" means there is a few being left out because the way $\mu $ is defined?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: As in "for almost every $x$". It formalises this idea.. - Does it converge on the whole real line? - No, it does not, but it converges almost everywhere!

Comment: To add to the given answers: one important reason why we only care about certain properties *almost everywhere* is because, at least with respect to integration, if two functions are equal almost everywhere, then their integrals are equal.  So if I have a function $f$, I can change its value on a set of measure $0$ with respect to the measure $\mu$, and the new function will have the same integral as $f$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I correct in saying that the adjective "almost everywhere" means there is a few being left out because the way μ is defined?

Yes, exactly that. Take for example the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Every countable set is a null-set w.r.t the Lebesgue measure, that means if your sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ on all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except for countably many $x$, this would still be convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am an happy camper.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: The convergence being spoken about here is pointwise, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is pointwise.

Comment: Also should add that countable sets aren't the only null sets. The Cantor Set is the typical example of an uncountable subset of R with (one-dimensional) Lebesgue measure zero.

Answer (score 6):

To put it another way, there exists a set $E$ with $\mu(E) = 0$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in D\setminus E$. The "almost everywhere" piece comes in as $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ eveywhere except possibly on $E$.

Comment: As always, thank you for your extra example!

Comment: When it says "converges everywhere" it means that the function "converges pointwise" ?

Comment: @user178403 convergence (almost) everywhere means convergence pointwise (almost) everywhere.

Comment: oh ok. Though it's not common to hear 'convergence pointwise everywhere', just 'convergence pointwise'. Or is there a difference among the two ?

Comment: @user178403, no there is no difference. Convergence pointwise is the standard terminology. The word ‘everywhere’ would go along with ‘almost’ as in “convergence almost everywhere.”

Comment: oh ok. thank you